# Fundamental question about related bar charts

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I'm trying to relate two bar charts that share the same x axis but different y axis from a json file. I have followed the multi focus example here:
https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/multi-focus.html

However, in my dataset the x axis will be consisted of strings so I changed the code a little:
note the scale band and units ordinal lines. After making the change the charts stopped utilizing the brush tool and selecting a bar is not effecting the chart 2 anymore. Can you point out what i am doing wrong here?

```
var chart1 = new dc.BarChart("#test1");
var chart2 = new dc.BarChart("#test2");
d3.json('wells.json').then(function(perfandcost) {

perfandcost.forEach(function(x) {
    x.fpd = +x.fpd;
});

var ndx                 = crossfilter(perfandcost),
    wells        = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.wellname;}),
    wellsGroup       = wells.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.fpd / 1000;}),
    wellcostsGroup       = wells.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.twc / 1000000;});


function bar_chart_fpd(chart) {
    chart
        .width(900)
        .height(375)
      .x(d3.scaleBand())
      .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        .dimension(wells)
        .ordinalColors(["rgba(253,175,75,0.7)"])
        .barPadding(0.2)
        .outerPadding(0.05)
        .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
        .group(wellsGroup);
    return chart;
}

    function bar_chart_twc(chart) {
    chart
        // .width(900)
        .height(375)
      .x(d3.scaleBand())
      .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
        // .brushOn(true)

        // .yAxisLabel("This is the Y Axis!")
        .dimension(wells)
        .ordinalColors(["rgba(253, 175, 75, 0.7)"])
        .barPadding(0.2)
        .outerPadding(0.05)
        .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
        // .useViewBoxResizing(true)
        .group(wellcostsGroup);
    return chart;
}

bar_chart_fpd(chart1)
  .brushOn(true)
bar_chart_twc(chart2);

function rangesEqual(range1, range2) {
    if (!range1 && !range2) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (!range1 || !range2) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (range1.length === 0 && range2.length === 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (range1[0].valueOf() === range2[0].valueOf() &&
        range1[1].valueOf() === range2[1].valueOf()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

chart1.focusCharts = function (chartlist) {
    if (!arguments.length) {
        return this._focusCharts;
    }
    this._focusCharts = chartlist; // only needed to support the getter above
    this.on('filtered', function (range_chart) {
        chartlist.forEach(function(focus_chart) {
            if (!rangesEqual(range_chart.filter(), focus_chart.filter())) {
                dc.events.trigger(function () {
                    focus_chart.focus(range_chart.filter());
                });
            }
        });
    });
    return this;
};

chart1.focusCharts([chart2]);
dc.renderAll();
});
```

Comment: Ordinal scale bar charts are not usually compatible with range/focus. It's possible to make it work but [it takes a lot of code](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/focus-ordinal-bar.html). If you really want multiple focus charts for one range chart, it's going to be some work combining those two examples, since neither feature is built-in.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a library that supports all of these features? I can change to something else since I'm still early in the process

Comment: You could try Vega Lite. It has crossfilter and range/focus features built-in. I haven't tried ordinal range/focus though.

Comment: Gordon, thanks for the advise. I was not aware of the vega lite and i was able to implement it and got a working prototype going. All i needed was easy to implement range/focus features since I am feeding it with Json data generated from Python code in the format that i need. Vega lite worked beautifully. Only downside compared to d3/dc is the lack of entry/exit animations which i can live without.